# CSS Universal Selector (*) not showing a border with parent element

Tags: css, selector

I have made a class ".ancestors" and assigned it to both parent and child divs. This class is showing border around the child div but not around the parent. Can someone please advise why is this happening? Which is the correct way here - *.ancestors or .ancestors * ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.ancestors *{ 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ancestors">
Parent
<div class="ancestors">Child</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the parent isn't targeted by the selector. The selector is `.ancestors *` which means "any element that is a descendant of an element with an `ancestors` class." The parent element *isn't* a descendant of an element with an `ancestors` class, so it isn't targeted. The child element is (whether or not the child has the class), because it's a descendant element of the parent element. If you wanted to target the parent and its descendants, you'd need the selector group `.ancestors, .ancestors *`, which applies the rules both to elements with that class and to their descendants.

Comment: in css `.ancestors *` mean all childs of elments with a `class="ancestors"`. and your "parent" is not this kind of child

Comment: You may find [the selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/) and [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) useful.

Comment: In this case you do not need the asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

`*.ancestors` - is any element that additionally has a class `ancestors`, but this is a waste of resources, it's the same as just `.ancestors` without `*`

`.ancestors *` - it is any child of a parent with a class `ancestors`.

Comment: @Pete it's not me, it's an autor issue. but yes, this selector is weird. )

Comment: @Pete not at all. in your case the `* .ancestors` selector is separated by a space. if there is no space, then the selector works as I described.

Comment: @Pete ok. i did it

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.ancestors { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

instead of

```
.ancestors *{ 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```